# Can I compile .c files as C++ files without renaming them?

Tags: visual-studio-2005

SVN is giving me some trouble with a few .c files that I had to rename in my branch because they received some C++ extensions. I could get around this trouble by somehow telling Visual Studio to treat all those files as C++ code, even if they have a .c extension.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: @Cthulhu huh? the questions aren't related at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set to "compile as C++" when right-clicking a file -> properties->c++->advanced. The trick is to not do it on the project, but for each individual file instead.

Ofc you can select multiple files when doing it, so it doesn't take you ages.